# How to monitor the spark-shell process through Java VisualVM?

Tags: java, apache-spark

Today I read a book which says I can monitor the spark-shell process through Java VisualVM by modifying the $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-class and adding the following thing:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=128m $OUR_JAVA_OPTS 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8300  
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1"
```

Then I start the $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell, and execute the following order in Linux,

```
netstat -tunlp
```

unfortunately, no program listens at port 8300, can anybody tell me the reason of this phenomenon please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The easiest way to use visualvm is to run as the same user on the same machine.

Comment: But the machine is in my virtual machine, and it does not have a graph interface, I have to connect in my windows machine.

Comment: In that case it is most likely a matter of enabling the host to see the port in the virtual machine - typically the easiest to get going is using Brigded networking..  However, I will encourage you to find out how to enable X11 forwarding from your virtual machine to your WIndows host.  For plain ssh this is "ssh -Y". You will also need a X11 emulator for Windows.

Comment: I think the key of the problem is that the port is not enabled, is something wrong with the setting? Do I miss something?

Comment: Hard to tell as you are not providing enough information about your environment.  Can you telnet to the port inside your virtual machine?

Comment: I tried "netstat -tunlp", no 8300 port was found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136229/discussion-between-coinnigh-and-thorbjorn-ravn-andersen).

Comment: There is a _lot_ of unknowns here.  Based on your responses so far I would suggest you start learning the works of visualvm on your Windows host and then start experimenting with remote connctions also on your Windows host.  Then when you feel comfortable with that, go back inside your virtual machine.